# how to add a webapi to an existing c# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a c# solution that contains my project in Microsoft Visual Studio and I want to add a webapi to it. How would I do that? Specifically what do I need to add references for to get it working?

Visual Studio Version:
Community 2015

.net Version: 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of visual studio?
Try adding via nuget.
https://www.nuget.org

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2015

Comment: Try right clicking the project and see if you have an "add a nuget package"